# Synonyme européen de "écœuranterie" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes, québec

Je suis à la recherche d'un mot signifiant *qualité de ce qui est repoussant, dégoutant*. J'ai trouvé [*écœuranterie*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/%C3%A9coeuranterie), mais malheureusement il se fait que ce mot n'est employé qu'au Canada. Existerait-il un synonyme qui serait compris en Europe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La source en question réfère au registre familier et donne comme synonymes : « abjection, bassesse, infamie, vilenie » (Usito). Par ailleurs on peut penser à « [dégueulasserie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9gueulasserie) », d'emploi populaire et sur le même [modèle](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-erie), signifiant soit le «  caractère de ce qui est dégueulasse » (Wiktionnaire) soit, par [métonymie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9gueulasserie), la « chose dégoûtante » elle-même (Wiktionnaire), sachant que [*dégueulasse*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9gueulasse) peut s'employer entre autres pour *dégoûtant*. On a peut-être aussi [*cochonnerie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cochonnerie) ou [*saloperie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saloperie), de registre familier, visant parfois plus la (l'absence de) valeur (d'où l'intérêt de présenter le phrase ou le contexte dans lequel on veut employer le mot).

Comment: Le registre ne convient pas ; « écœuranterie » est évidemment d'un registre assez élevé, voire soutenu.

Comment: @LPH La [source](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/%C3%A9coeuranterie) dit « familier ».

Comment: La source est un peu en dessous et « familier » pour « saloperie » un peu trop haut ; ça fait un bon décalage.

Comment: De quoi tu parles ?? Usito dit « Qc. Fam. » : « La marque familier est utilisée pour marquer un emploi de registre familier, c'est-à-dire moins valorisé socialement qu'un emploi standard ou neutre; la marque familier peut parfois correspondre, en raison du contexte d’emploi, à une certaine valeur stylistique, expressive. ». [Saloperie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saloperie) est familier aussi. Il n'y a aucun décalage, de plus _saloperie_ est une suggestion secondaire, _dégueulasserie_ étant la principale. Ton propos ne s'appuie sur rien du tout. @LPH

Comment: Afin d'éviter de potentiels débats sur ce désaccord, je vous propose de continuer cette discussion [dans le chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127234/discussion-on-answer-by-escarlate-adamantine-synonyme-europeen-de-ecoeuranterie).

Answer (score 0):

Je répond au titre de votre question plutôt qu'à la question elle-même : on dirait tout simplement « des saletés » ou « des choses épouvantables » (ou dégoutantes, dégueulasses, etc. selon le sens). Sur un régistre familier/vulgaire on peut dire « des dégueulasseries » ou « des saloperies ».

Answer (score -2):

La définition que vous mentionnez ne concerne pas une qualité mais un acte dont une des qualités est celle d'être repoussant, dégoutant.

> écœuranterie [ekœʀɑ̃tʀi] n. f.
> Québec fam. Geste ou parole qui inspire le mépris, le dégoût.

Si c'était de cette qualité qu'il s'agissait il faudrait avoir recours à une expression parce qu'il n'existe pas souvent de nom en français. Par exemple la qualité de ce qui est bas est la bassesse, la qualité de ce qui est vil est la vilénie et la qualité de ce qui est infame est l'infamie, mais la qualité de ce qui est abject n'est pas identifiée par un mot, la qualité de ce qui est répulsif (« répulsivité » pourrait-on dire) n'existe pas en tant que mot, etc. — Le français n'est pas comme l'anglais, lequel comprend le plus souvent le terme correspondant, même s'il n'est pas souvent utilisé.

Comme on dirait « un acte d'une vilénie peu commune » (par exemple) on dirait « un acte de nature à inspirer le dégout de façon peu commune ».

Il en est de même pour l'acte qui a une qualité donnée. Un acte infame est une infamie, un acte vil une vilénie, mais in n'y a pas d'équivalent sur ce modèle pour un acte dégoutant (sauf en Québécois, puisque « écœuranterie » est défini comme tel dans ce vernaculaire).

Il faut donc utiliser des expressions.

- *un acte répugnant/écœurant/dégoutant*
- *un action  répugnante/écœurante/dégoutante*

Comment: Comment justifie-t-on ce vote négatif ?

Comment: Peut-être l'affirmation que le mot *répulsivité* n'existe pas...

Comment: @jlliagre Comme il n'est pas dans le TLFi, il a été introduit tout récemment (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9pulsivit%C3%A9).

Comment: Attesté en [1843](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Recueil_de_m%C3%A9decine_v%C3%A9t%C3%A9rinaire/ohIHAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22r%C3%A9pulsivit%C3%A9%22&pg=PA557&printsec=frontcover) , donc pas exactement "tout récemment". Le français est une langue vivante. C'est l'usage qui prévaut. Les dictionnaires ne font que l'enregistrer, ils ne le définissent pas.